Analyzing Transaction Dependencies and Deadlock in Database Systems
Look at the following partial schedule involving four transactions T1, T2, T3 and T4; and the data items A, B, and C.
Partial Schedule:
T4_lock_X(A); T4_R(A); T1_lock_X(B); T1_R(B); T4_W(A); T3_lock_S(C); T3_R(C); T2_lock_S(B); T2_R(B); T2_lock_S(C); T4_lock_S(B); T3_releaseLock(C); T1_W(B);T1_releaseLock(B); T4_releaseLock(A);
Note:
T2_lock_S(A) – means T2 locks data item A in Share mode.
T1_lock_X(B) – means T1 locks data item B in Exclusive mode.
T2_R(A)- means T2 reads data item A
T3_W(A) - means T3 writes data item A
T2_releaseLock(B)- means T2 release lock on data item B
Check if the above partial schedule results in a deadlock by drawing a wait-for graph. Give your reasoning, not just a yes or no answer. Give the final wait-for graph.
Could you please help me understand and solve a deadlock scenario? I have a partial schedule involving transactions T1, T2, T3, and T4, along with their actions on data items A, B, and C. I'm trying to construct a wait-for graph to identify any potential deadlock cycles. Could you explain how to approach this analysis and interpret the dependencies between transactions based on their locking behaviors?
